# self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController returning nil

Tags: ios, rootview, rootviewcontroller

`self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController`

always returning **nil** though there is viewController available.
Not sure what i am doing wrong.

**Below is the full code-**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

NSLog(@"this is loaded");
if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

    if (secondController.isPresented)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: How you present view controller?

Comment: using tableview delegate method, Did select row at index,

Comment: detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];

Comment: Please check my edited answer

Comment: So, you just want to check your specific view controller is presented or pushed , and wants to also check top view controller is your specific viewcontroller or not ?

Comment: Why checking with only pushed or presented, ideally you have to write code for both if (presented) else (pushed) then identify your class.

Comment: Thanks i am checking for both now

Answer (score 1):

`self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController`. I think it returns you `UINavigationController` type class. Please check inside the log or debug.

```
 UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

NSArray *arrayVC =navigationController.viewControllers;
        for (UIViewController* viewController in arrayVC) {

                //This if condition checks whether the viewController's class is SecondViewController
                 if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]] ) 
                {
                    //Do something
                }

          }
```

Comment: Yes i am getting UINavigationController

Comment: What you are getting in arrayVC? Let me know.

Comment: i am getting 4 viewcontrollers

Comment: Basically i want identify a particular viewcontroller , and the supported orientatin for that  particular viewcontroller will be landscape.

Comment: So now you will get inside my if condition and check your logic.

Comment: Ok let me check Thanks :)

Comment: @iosDev Welcome :-)

Comment: @iosDev Accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115837/discussion-between-bhadresh-mulsaniya-and-iosdev).

Answer (score 1):

```
if([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
     if([navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
     {
             SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

             if (secondController.isPresented){
                  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
             }
             else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
     }
     else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Edited :**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

Replace with this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:detailViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Still getting nil :(

Comment: Basically i want identify a particular viewcontroller , and the supported orientatin for that  particular viewcontroller will be landscape.

Comment: @iosDev Please Check my Answer.

Comment: @iosDev you are pushing VC that's why `presentedViewController ` return nil.

Comment: @iosDev Welcome. Please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: after presenting view controller navigation bar got disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Try around this code. here you could check is it presented or pushed and also could check your specific class.

```
UIViewController *vcTmp = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if([[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentingViewController] presentedViewController])
{

    // Now your viewcontroller is presented

    vcTmp = [[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentingViewController] presentedViewController];

    if ([vcTmp isKindOfClass:[MasterViewController class]]){

            // Your class is identified here

    }

}
else
{

    // Now your viewcontroller is pushed

    vcTmp = [[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentingViewController] presentedViewController];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [appDelegate.window.rootViewController childViewControllers];

    vcTmp = (UIViewController*)viewControllers.lastObject;

    if ([vcTmp isKindOfClass:[MasterViewController class]]){

            // Your class is identified here

    }

}
```